# Login system keeps saying that I can't login

Tags: php, authentication, system

I'm following a guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3Wxi-ZvUng) now I'm done with this part of the login system but now it doesn't work, I did everything like the guy on the tutorial does and I have watched it three times after to make sure my code was the same as his and it is. I have it running on a local server and made two users in the database. (I follow the tutorial trough all of this)

I have already asked for the solution in the comment section but the video is from three years ago and no reply yet.

```php
function getLogin($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
            if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                header("Location: index.php?loginsuccess");
                exit();
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: include.php?loginfailed");
            exit();
        }   
    }
}

function userLogout() {
    if (isset($_POST['logoutSubmit'])) {
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: include.php");
        exit();
    }   
}
```

**View**

```php
<?php
    echo "<form method='POST' action='".getLogin($conn)."'>
        <input type='text' name='iud'>
        <input type='password' name='pwd'>
        <button type='submit' name='loginSubmit'>Login</button>
    </form>";
    echo "<form method='POST' action='".userLogout()."'>
        <button type='submit' name='logoutSubmit'>Logout</button>
    </form>";

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo "You are logged in!";
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged in!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? That's a lot of code, and it's widely open to SQL injection

Comment: What sense is `action='".getLogin($conn)."'` supposed to make? That function does not return any value that could be concatenated into the HTML code you are creating there to begin with. If this is actually from that tutorial, then the tutorial is probably rather nonsensical to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, (i think) this function returns a value from the database (the user name/pwd) but the problem was i had iud instead of uid in my .getlogin function

Comment: No, this function does not return anything. If `$_POST['loginSubmit']` is not set, it doesn’t do anything, and if it is, it only tries to redirect to a different URL, depending on success or failure. So to try and use it to fill the action attribute of the form makes no sense at all here. (If you want to hear my advice/opinion - go get your eyes off the 'tube, and your nose into a book instead. I don’t get how people can seriously expect to learn programming by watching a couple of YT vids to begin with …)

Comment: I recommend to look for a better tutorial.

Comment: i get ur point, but when i tried to use w3schools or other sites that are made for learning to code people tell me to watch youtube tutorials (and till now this works better for me and i learned more from yt in a day than using sites like w3schools) and now i use youtube people tell me not to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['logoutSubmit'])) {
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: include.php");
    exit();
}   
 if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])) {
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='$uid' AND pwd='$pwd'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
        if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            header("Location: index.php?loginsuccess");
            exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: include.php?loginfailed");
        exit();
    }   
} ?>

<form method='POST' action="#">
    <input type='text' name='iud'>
    <input type='password' name='pwd'>
    <button type='submit' name='loginSubmit'>Login</button>
    <button type='submit' name='logoutSubmit'>Logout</button>
</form>
```

Bear in mind this has SQL injection and plain-text password vulnerabilities, so you should not put this live on the internet.